# Json.Net Deserialization of Complex Objects - Base Class that Contains a Base Class as a Property

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net, json-deserialization

I have been attempting to resolve this issue for several hours. I have tried many approaches and read many posts. I can't seem to find a resolution.

I have an object hierarchy whereby I have derived types that contain another derived type. I am using Json.Net's `TypeNameHandling` setting. I have it set to `Auto` on both serialization and deserialization.

The resulting JSON is:

```
"[\r\n  {\r\n    \"$type\": \"Common.Monitors.HeartbeatMonitor, Common\",\r\n    \"ClassName\": \"HeartbeatMonitor\",\r\n    \"ServerGroupMonitorId\": 1,\r\n    \"Instructions\": {\r\n      \"$type\": \"Common.Monitors.HeartbeatMonitorInstructions, Common\",\r\n      \"RunIntervalInMinutes\": 1\r\n    },\r\n    \"LastExecutionDateTime\": \"2016-03-22T16:35:18.7458519\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"$type\": \"Common.Monitors.DiskSpaceMonitor, Common\",\r\n    \"ClassName\": \"DiskSpaceMonitor\",\r\n    \"ServerGroupMonitorId\": 2,\r\n    \"Instructions\": {\r\n      \"$type\": \"Common.Monitors.DiskSpaceMonitorInstructions, Common\",\r\n      \"DriveLetter\": \"C:\\\",\r\n      \"AlertWhenPercentFreeLessThan\": 20,\r\n      \"RunIntervalInMinutes\": 30\r\n    },\r\n    \"LastExecutionDateTime\": \"2016-03-22T16:15:18.7458519\"\r\n  }\r\n]"
```

When attempting to deserialize using the following:

```
string json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

IEnumerable<MonitorBase> monitors = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<MonitorBase>>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
            });
```

I receive the following exception:

> An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code.
>
> Additional information: Error converting value
>
> ```
> "[
>    {
>      "$type": "Common.Monitors.HeartbeatMonitor, Common",
>      "ClassName": "HeartbeatMonitor",
>      "ServerGroupMonitorId": 1,
>      "Instructions": {
>        "$type": "Common.Monitors.HeartbeatMonitorInstructions, Common",
>        "RunIntervalInMinutes": 1
>      },
>      "LastExecutionDateTime": "2016-03-22T16:35:18.7458519"
>    },
>    {
>      "$type": "Common.Monitors.DiskSpaceMonitor, Common",
>      "ClassName": "DiskSpaceMonitor",
>      "ServerGroupMonitorId": 2,
>      "Instructions": {
>        "$type": "Common.Monitors.DiskSpaceMonitorInstructions, Common",
>        "DriveLetter": "C:\\",
>        "AlertWhenPercentFreeLessThan": 20,
>        "RunIntervalInMinutes": 30
>      },
>      "LastExecutionDateTime": "2016-03-22T16:15:18.7458519"
>    }
> ]"
> ```
>
> to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Common.Monitors.MonitorBase]'.
>   Path '', line 1, position 943.

The `HeartbeatMonitor` and `DiskSpaceMonitor` types derive from `MonitorBase` and their respective `Instructions` types derive from `MonitorInstructionBase`.

I can't help but assume that I am missing something obvious as I can't imagine that this isn't a rather common scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the problem might be that your JSON is double-serialized, as evidenced by the escaped quote marks `\"`, the visible newlines `\r\n` and the fact that the whole JSON is quoted.  When you deserialize double-serialized JSON, the result is a string, not an object, which clearly cannot be converted to an `IEnumerable<T>` of any kind.  Hence the error.

If you control the source of the JSON, be sure that you are serializing your objects only once.  A common cause of the problem is in not realizing that some  frameworks, such as Web API, do serialization automatically for you, so if you are serializing your objects manually first before returning them then you'll end up with double-serialized JSON.

If you do not control the source of the JSON, and/or you cannot get the owner to fix it, then you can correct for it on the client side by deserializing the JSON twice: first to get the "real" JSON string, then second to produce your objects from that.  For example:

```
string escapedJson = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

string realJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(escapedJson);

IEnumerable<MonitorBase> monitors = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<MonitorBase>>(realJson, 
        new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
        });
```

**EDIT**

I see from your comment that you are manually serializing your object in order to make use of Json.Net's TypeNameHandling setting, and you're looking for a way to avoid the double serialization.

You basically have two options:

1. Add the `TypeNameHandling` setting to Web API's global serialization settings and remove the manual serialization code from your method.  To do this, add the following in the `Application_Start()` method in your `global.asax`.

   ```
   var settings = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
   settings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
   ```
2. Alternatively, you can change your Web API method to create and return an `HttpResponseMessage` with a `StringContent` object containing your JSON and with the `mediaType` set to `application/json`.  This should prevent Web API from trying to re-serialize the result.

   ```
   string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(monitors, new JsonSerializerSettings 
   {
       TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
       Formatting = Formatting.Indented
   }); 
   HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
   response.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
   return response;
   ```

Comment: Thanks Brian. I control both sides of the process and I am using Web API. However, I am not manually serializing the data so I'll need to figure out why the double-serialization is occurring but what you're saying makes sense.

Comment: Ok, so I think the issue is related to the fact that I need to use Json.Net's TypeNameHandling settings in order to get the $type information into the serialized json. So yes, I am performing a JsonConvert.SerializeObject, with TypeNameHandling settings, and then return that string. Web API appears to be serializing the json yet again. Is there a way to prevent that from happening? I have't found anything obvious.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more information which should help solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks again, Brian. Your approach solves the serialization issue. I still have another issue related to deserialization but it's just something else I am going to have to address. Thanks again for the assistance.

Comment: No problem; glad I could help.